# Upload Image in CEWP without Rad Editor (WSS 3.0)

Tags: rich-text, image-display

I have a Project Web Access (WSS 3.0) site collection where I can't use the Telerik Rad Editor as a rich text editor (long story). My problem is that my users are accustomed to the Rad Editor's image manager feature that lets them upload images directly to an image library and insert them into a rich text field. Any clever suggestions (like Javascript, jQuery, SPServices, etc.) for working around this? My users will flat out reject the default "upload, copy URL, paste" method that the CEWP requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't extend the CEWP, so your only option is to work out RAD, or develop an alternative your self.

James McCormack had a similar issue (needed to extend CEWP).

He used reflector to dig into the CEWP, and took the relevant code, and implemented it in a visual web part solution.  His solution is targeted at 2010, but you could use a similiar approach and leverage Jan Tielens SmartPart ( http://smartpart.codeplex.com/ )

You would need to add the relevant code of course to implement an image manager type solution.

Here is the link for James' post:
http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2010/09/develop-custom-editable-visual-web-part.html

This is code for uploading image from Charles Lee

http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/charleslee/archive/2009/10/21/75594.aspx

```
Dim streamImage As Stream = Nothing 
If fleInput.HasFile Then 
    streamImage = fleInput.PostedFile.InputStream 
End If

Using Site As New SPSite("SITECOLLECTIONURL") 
    Using Web As SPWeb = Site.OpenWeb("SITEURL") 
        Dim pics As SPList = Web.Lists("PICTURELIBRARYNAME") 
        pics.RootFolder.Files.Add( _ 
            fleInput.FileName, streamImage) 
    End Using 
End Using
```

At this point, you would need to have the full URL path to the image, and inject the  tag into your editor.

Comment: Thanks Jesus... this one is probably beyond my available resources so I may have to circle back on Rad Editor as that's what I use in my MOSS site collections. Appreciate the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I've always been fond of [RightJS](http://rightjs.org/ui/rte/demo)'s RTE.  I admit, I haven't implemented it for use with images, but there is a post on [SPServices forum](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/221435) that discusses how to handle file uploading.  You should be able to extend the RTE to grab files from desktops instead of URL's and send them to the appropriate library.

Comment: It's been so long since I've had to develop an actual 'solution' I'd forgotten about these. You could definitely utilize the web services to implement the upload function thru one of these  JSRTE's as another alternative.